# Postfix rejecting my SMTP client

Tags: postfix, zimbra

I am writing a JavaMail client (running in a GlassFish 4 server) and I have been unable to get my Zimbra ZCS server to accept the SMTP session.   Invariably I get the following error in **zimbra.log**:

```
Dec 19 04:51:05 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[24088]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from c-24-6-111-204.hsd1.ca.comcast.net[24.6.111.204]: 554 5.7.1 <c-24-6-111-204.hsd1.ca.comcast.net[24.6.111.204]>: Client host rejected: Access denied; from=<info@myserver.com> to=<info@ myserver.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<192.168.88.12>
```

I have added my local local system's IP address (both private and public) to the postfix configuration as follows:

```
$ postconf mynetworks
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128 10.1.0.0/16 64.71.111.112/28 24.6.111.204/32 192.168.88.0/24
```

The subnet 64.71.111.112 includes the public IP address of the server.  The 24.6.111.204 address is the public IPv4 address of my NAT router.

On my JavaMail client I have set the following properties:

```
mail.smtp.port = 587
mail.smtp.auth = true
mail.smtp.starttls.enable = true
mail.user = 'info@myserver.com'
mail.smtp.password = 'thepassword'
```

I am really stuck -- can someone suggest a checklist of things to check to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out the problem was a typo in my Glassfish properties settings. I had the property name as **mail.starttls.enable** when it should have been (as shown above) **mail.smtp.starttls.enable**. Just one more illustration how you can waste a lot of time by not seeing something that you should see.

I believe the protocol stack on the server side does not log anything more helpful than the "Access Denied" message because it has no reason to believe that the client did not intend to not use a TLS session.

Instead of deleting this post I will leave it up in case someone in the future finds it helpful. I have found no good guides or tutorials in making the combination of Glassfish 4, JavaMail, and Zimbra ZCS to work together.